# Summation of a list to list of lists Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

By using the code`MapThread[Plus,{{a,b},{{c,d},{e,f},{g,h}}}]` , i need the result as follows `{{a+c,b+d},{a+e, b+f},{a+g, b+h}}`.

Comment: `{a + #1, b + #2} & @@@ {{c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}`

Check the `Function` (that's the & symbol) and the `Apply` (that's the @@@) documentation for what that means.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @EmadRaslan lowriniak's solution works for me. Are you sure you copied it correctly?

Comment: I am so sorry, It works, thank you very much

Comment: How to apply it on the case `{{a, b}, {c, d}} + {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, l}}} = {{{a + e, b + f}, {c + g, d + h}}, {{a + i, b + j}, {c + k, d + l}}}`

Comment: @EmadRaslan try to modify Iowriniak's solution to use `/@` (`Map`) instead of `@@@`. That should extend to your new case.

Comment: @EmadRaslan In fact, lowriniak's solution will work for this new input.

Comment: It works thank you

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

```
vec = {a, b};
mat = {{c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}};

Transpose[vec + Transpose[mat]]
```

> ```
> {{a + c, b + d}, {a + e, b + f}, {a + g, b + h}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is the solution of my problem

Comment: @EmadRaslan 1. You are spamming by asking this in multiple places. 2. This is a completely separate question and is therefore off topic. Make a new question and show any work you have attempted to help ensure the most helpful results.

Comment: how to apply for the function `UXX11[a_, b_, m_, n_, s_, t_]` in the file [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B50gSYQtXXPbZl94YUNDd1hNa2s/view)

Comment: @EmadRaslan Read my second bullet point from above: **2. This is a completely separate question from your original and is therefore off topic. Make a new question and show any work you have attempted to help ensure the most helpful results.**

Answer (score 3):

```
mat = {{c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}};
vec = {a, b};
```

Using `Threaded` (new in 13.1)

```
mat + Threaded[vec]
```

{{a + c, b + d}, {a + e, b + f}, {a + g, b + h}}

Using `Inner`

```
Inner[Plus, mat, vec, List]
```

{{a + c, b + d}, {a + e, b + f}, {a + g, b + h}}

Answer (score 2):

A shorter version using `Outer`:

```
mat = {{c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}};
vec = {a, b};

Diagonal /@ Outer[Plus, mat, vec]

(*{{a + c, b + d}, {a + e, b + f}, {a + g, b + h}}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ls = {{a, b}, {{c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}}; 
Flatten[Outer[Plus, {First@ls}, Last@ls, 1], 1]
```

> {{a + c, b + d}, {a + e, b + f}, {a + g, b + h}}

Comment: Thank you, how to apply it on the case `{{a, b}, {c, d}} + {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, l}}} = {{{a + e, b + f}, {c + g, d + h}}, {{a + i, b + j}, {c + k, d + l}}}`

Comment: ls = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, l}}}}; 
fn[a1_, a2_] := Outer[Plus , {a1}, a2, 1]
Transpose[Flatten[MapThread[fn, {ls[[1]], Transpose[ls[[2]]]}], 1]]

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
TranslationTransform[{a, b}][{{c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}}]
   {{a + c, b + d}, {a + e, b + f}, {a + g, b + h}}
```

Comment: If I want to apply on `{{a, b}, {c, d}} + {{{e, f}, {g, h}}, {{i, j}, {k, l}}} = {{{a + e, 
    b + f}, {c + g, d + h}}, {{a + i, b + j}, {c + k, d + l}}}`